# Are tensor names always prepended with "import/" when loaded from protobuf?

Tags: tensorflow

When I load a (frozen) Tensorflow model from disk using:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
  with graph.as_default():
        f = gfile.FastGFile("frozen_graph.pb", "rb")
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
```

It seems that all tensor names are prepended with  import/ .
 This is the code I use to print the names:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        all_ops = sess.graph.get_operations()
        op_values =  [op.values() for op in all_ops]
        for values in op_values:
            for each in value:
                print each.name
```

Why? Is this some kind of default option that can be overriden? Or can I rely on this in my code? I could not find this documented anyhwere, can anybody point me to references regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default value specified in [`tf.import_graph_def`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def).
You can pass in a `name` argument to use a different prefix.